# "How to get actual text value(Place name) from LatLong ?"

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am working on GoogleMap in Android.

So far, I have got the current location and displayed marker on it.

I got LatLong value from my current location.

I am able to get city name using following code :

```
            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation( mLocation.getLatitude(), mLocation.getLongitude(), 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (addresses.size() > 0)
            System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+addresses.get(0).getLocality(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

But, can't get the atual area name i.e. **Bodakdev char rasta**, Ahmedabad.

Now, my question is: **How to get actual text value (Place name) from LatLong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this by `Geocoder` object in your google map. The method `getFromLocation(double, double, int)` does the work.

```
Geocoder geocoder;
List<Address> addresses;
geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); //  1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5

String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional     address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
```

Comment: ya I can get the city name by using above code, but what if i want to do as suggested in above edits ?

Comment: See my edited answer. This will give you all the details. And NULL if info is not available for that input set. @JaiminModi

Answer (score 1):

Use this,

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(MyLat, MyLong, 1);
String cityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
String stateName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
String countryName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also get city name from zip-Code or postal-code of the place

```
private fun getLatLngByZipcode(zipcode: String): String {
    var place = context.getString(R.string.location)
    val geocoder = Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault())
    try {
        val addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(zipcode, 5)
        addresses?.forEach{
            it?.locality?.apply {
                place=this
            }
        }
    }
    catch (e: IOException) {
        LogUtils.error(TAG,e.message)
    }
    return place
}
```